# Can't find SDL_LoadBMP() entry point in 'SDL.DLL' with PInvoke

Tags: c#, dll, pinvoke, sdl

I'm trying to marshal data between SDL and my C# .NET program.  The first few calls that I make into SDL.DLL work fine, inasmuch as I get no error and my Windows console app does open an empty application window:

```
My_SDL_Funcs.SDL_Init(0x0000FFFF); // SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING
IntPtr scrn = My_SDL_Funcs.SDL_SetVideoMode(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, SCREEN_BPP, 0x00000000); // SDL_SWSURFACE
screen = (SDL_Surface)Marshal.PtrToStructure(scrn, typeof(SDL_Surface));
My_SDL_Funcs.SDL_WM_SetCaption("Hello World", null);
// ...
```

When I try to call SDL_LoadBMP() however, I get this runtime error:

> Unable to find an entry point named 'SDL_LoadBMP' in DLL 'SDL'.

The SDL doc says that SDL_LoadBMP takes a const char* file name and returns a pointer to a SDL_Surface struct.

I first tried declaring the PInvoke as:

```
[DllImport("SDL", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern IntPtr SDL_LoadBMP([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string file);
```

When this didn't work, I tried:

```
public static extern IntPtr SDL_LoadBMP(IntPtr file);
```

and used:

```
IntPtr fn = Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi(filename);
IntPtr loadedImage = My_SDL_Funcs.SDL_LoadBMP(fn);
```

Assuming that that the function actuall does exist in this library (SDL.DLL version 1.2.14), am I using the wrong invocation for a const char*?

Comment: the code that you said worked a few times.. can you post that .. unless I am not seeing it.. sounds like either an issue with Releasing the Marshaled Instance or some method that you are trying to call my or maynot be a static method.. but I am willing to guess that you are not releasing the unmanaged resource properly..

Comment: @DJ KRAZE - I modified the original question to include working calls.

Comment: cool I also would go with @GalacticJello's answer I didn't think to try the call on my own local.. good catch ther GalacticJello

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I downloaded the DLL version you are using, and could not find an export for SDL_LoadBMP.

There is a SDL_LoadBMP_RW, though, so you could rig up your own helper call like so:

```
private const string SDL = "SDL.dll";

[DllImport(SDL, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl), SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
public static extern IntPtr SDL_LoadBMP_RW(IntPtr src, int freesrc);

[DllImport(SDL, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl), SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
public static extern IntPtr SDL_RWFromFile(string file, string mode);

public static IntPtr SDL_LoadBMP(string file)
{
    return SDL_LoadBMP_RW(SDL_RWFromFile(file, "rb"), 1);
}
```

**UPDATE**:

I had a look through the code, and the call you are looking for is defined as a macro, so that is why you can't call it directly.  Using the above code basically does the same thing as the macro defintion:

```
#define SDL_LoadBMP(file) SDL_LoadBMP_RW(SDL_RWFromFile(file, "rb"), 1)
```

Comment: That's weird, because I built and ran the Lazy Foo SDL Lesson on surface loading and blitting from here - http://lazyfoo.net/SDL_tutorials/lesson02/index.php - and it definitely makes that SDL_LoadBMP call.  I have several SDL versions on my machine, and never understand how you can tell which version of a DLL Windows is picking up.  One has a dll called SDL_Image.DLL.  I wonder if the function was moved there in some version.

Comment: It's not actually an exported function, but defined as a macro, that's why you couldn't call it from C#.

Comment: Yeah, your post caused me to search the SDL headers and I found that too: #define SDL_LoadBMP(file) SDL_LoadBMP_RW(SDL_RWFromFile(file, "rb"), 1) As noted above, nice catch!